# Django rest framework Settings config with this Site already exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework is giving the following error when we attempt to perform a PUT to existing serialized data:

```
Settings config with this <data> already exists.
```

This is coming from the API Browser and from a Restangular connection from the browser. 
Our serializer looks like this:

```
class SmartPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    """ Sort of a hack to get past the demo """
    def from_native(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            data = data['id']
        return super(SmartPrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).from_native(data)

class SettingsConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = SmartPrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='site')
    class Meta:
        model = SettingsConfig
        fields = ('site', 'expire_session_on_browser_close', 'idle_timeout_minutes', 'id')
```

DFR doesn't seem to have any problems picking up on the id because it know the Id exists, it just wants to create an entry with the Id instead of updating the old entry.